# Spotify List : Highlight next/previous track

Tags: spotify

On my spotify app, if I click on player to play track,  the track is highlighted in the list-view. But when I click on the next button of spotify the next track in the list-view is not highlighted, even when it is  being played...the highlighting is totally lost. And I do not know how to do it. 
 It works if I just reload the app or I go on next tab. Can anyone guide me as how to fix this? Thanks in advance :-)

```
models.Track.fromURI(track, function(track) {
  models.Album.fromURI(track.album.uri, function(album) {            
      var pl = new views.Player(); 
      pl.context = album;             
      document.getElementById('imag').appendChild ( pl.node );

      var tracklist = new views.List(album);      
      tracklist.node.classList.add("sp-list");
      $("#song1").append(tracklist.node);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work without any problems, since you are using the same `context` for both 
`Player` and `List` views. In fact, I have tested it and it works for me (note that I have added a couple of missing lines):

```js
  var sp = getSpotifyApi(),
    models = sp.require("$api/models"),
    views = sp.require("$api/views"),
    track = "spotify:track:6G0RXhQJGDnjgUdbQfBZRk";

  models.Track.fromURI(track, function(track) {
    models.Album.fromURI(track.album.uri, function(album) {
      var pl = new views.Player();
      pl.context = album;
      document.getElementById("imag").appendChild(pl.node);

      var tracklist = new views.List(album);
      tracklist.node.classList.add("sp-list");
      document.getElementById("song1").appendChild(tracklist.node);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you @JMPerez for letting me know that it works for you. So that means there is no problem with the code :-)